# AWS Java - Assume Role from a lambda to call API gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, assume-role

how do I assume role from lambda to call a API gateway using java SDK

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're referring to the API Gateway generated Java SDK. The Client Builder has a method `public void setIamCredentials(AWSCredentialsProvider iamCredentials)`. You can pass into that method a AWSStaticCredentialsProvider which can be generated as follows:

```
AWSSecurityTokenService client = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().build();
AssumeRoleRequest request = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(iamRole)
            .withRoleSessionName(yourRoleName);

AssumeRoleResult response = client.assumeRole(request);

return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
            new BasicSessionCredentials(
                    response.getCredentials().getAccessKeyId(),
                    response.getCredentials().getSecretAccessKey(),
                    response.getCredentials().getSessionToken()));
```

Remember that you will need to set an IAM policy on the Role that allows it to access your API Gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Comment: I am not using the generated sdk. I do not have access to the aws account to generate the API.